# Android import SQLite database in SQLiteOpenHelper object

Tags: android

I have created a database using my `object` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
I managed to upload my `DataBase` file into cloud and download them when the application is opened and the `database` is not yet created. When the download finishes I would like to open the database already populated. Is there a way how can I achieve this ? I have searched for past 2 days how can I do this but I quite not understand.

My database class is this:

```
public class MusicDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "MusicDB.sqlite";
    private Context context;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    public static final String TABLE_CONFIG = "config";
    public static final String TABLE_SONGS = "songs";
    public static final String TABLE_PLAYLISTS = "playlists";
    public static final String TABLE_PLAYLISTS_SONGS = "playlists_songs";

    // CONFIG TABLE //
    public static final String config_id = "id";
    public static final String config_Directory = "Directory";
    /////////////////

    // SONGS TABLE //
    public static final String songs_id = "id";
    public static final String songs_name = "Name";
    public static final String songs_path = "Path";
    public static final String songs_downloadLing = "downloadLink";
    ////////////////

    // PLAYLISTS TABLE //
    public static final String playlists_id = "id";
    public static final String playlists_name = "Name";
    ////////////////////

    // PLAYLISTS SONGS TABLE //
    public static final String playlists_songs_id = "id";
    public static final String playlists_songs_playlistid = "playlist_id";
    public static final String playlists_songs_songid = "song_id";
    //////////////////////////

//    public MusicDB(Context context, StorageApi api, String mountId) {
//        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        this.api = api;
//        this.mountID = mountId;
//    }

    public MusicDB(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir("") + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        context.openOrCreateDatabase(context.getExternalFilesDir("")+DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

//        try {
//            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
//            db.close();
//        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

//        db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(context.getExternalFilesDir("")+DATABASE_NAME, null);

        final String CREATE_CONFIG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_CONFIG+" ("+config_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+config_Directory+" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONFIG_TABLE);

        final String CREATE_SONGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_SONGS+" ("+songs_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+songs_name+" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,"+songs_path+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+songs_downloadLing+" TEXT UNIQUE)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SONGS_TABLE);

        final String CREATE_PLAYLISTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_PLAYLISTS+" ("+playlists_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+playlists_name+" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYLISTS_TABLE);

        final String CREATE_PLAYLISTS_SONGS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_PLAYLISTS_SONGS+" ("+playlists_songs_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+playlists_songs_playlistid+" INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
                playlists_songs_songid+" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("+playlists_songs_playlistid+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_PLAYLISTS+"("+playlists_id+") ON DELETE CASCADE," +
                "FOREIGN KEY ("+playlists_songs_songid+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_SONGS+"("+songs_id+") ON DELETE CASCADE);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYLISTS_SONGS);
//        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("TEST", "Se apeleaza onUPDATE");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONFIG);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SONGS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAYLISTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAYLISTS_SONGS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addDirectory(String name) {

        Log.i("TEST", "Adaug in Config " + name);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(config_Directory, name);

        db.insert(TABLE_CONFIG, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDirectories() {
        ArrayList<String> directories = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_CONFIG;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                directories.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return directories;
    }
}
```

As you can see I did comment all my lines with everything I've tried so far.

Edit1: One ideea that I had these days was to create a DUMP .SQL file and upload it to cloud, and when the database is created to run the query from file but I can't find any method to export the file from db.

Comment: Why do you create the tables? If you download (where is the code?) a prepopulated db, then you don't need that redundancy.

Comment: Because if there is no database file on cloud and can't be downloaded the database should be created and after uploaded to the cloud.

Comment: It seems such an overkill, to me. Make your db first (SQLite Manager, anyone?) and put it on the cloud. Better would be to have a LIVE database on a server, accessed through webservices.

Comment: Every user of this app need to have the database on cloud, I can't force the database on every user cloud and I also don't have access of a server for a live database.

Comment: No, every user needs to acces a database with their credentials. This is the typical way to do things with a live db. You know... creating a db, sending it to a server, downloading it again... Such a network pressure! Then why not having an offline local database once and for all?

Comment: Because they might change the phone, having more than 1 device etc .. and they need to have the option to use the same database from one point to more than 1 device.

Comment: no need for `SQLiteOpenHelper` then, just use `SQLiteDatabase#openDatabase`

Comment: If the database has to be accessed by more than one device, then a live db should be your preferred option.